# Adding a Shortcut Link for the MathJax Tutorial

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

> Can we create a custom "magic link" which points to the MathJax tutorial?  That is, would it be possible to have MSE expand something like  `[help/mathjax]` into a link to the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)?

It was recently brought to my attention that MSE has a ton of really useful little shortcut links for chat and comments.  For example, the text `[math.se]` gets expanded out to a link to the main page, i.e. "[Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/)".  More details can be found on the [Meta Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000).

I often find myself linking to the MathJax tutorial in the comments attached to both questions and answers, and in my trawling of the review queues, my perception is that there are a lot of other "janitors" who are encountering the same problem.  I would go so far as to conjecture that

`Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)`

is one of the most common comment types on the website.  As such, I think it might be helpful to have a magic link to the MathJax tutorial.

Comment: I think it has been previous suggested to have a "magic link" to the [help/notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) page, which in turn has links to the MathJax Basic Tutorial and Quick Reference.

Comment: @hardmath Yeah, I kind of thought that such a thing might have been asked for before, but I couldn't turn up anything on Meta.  If you (or anyone else) can find a previous question where this idea is discussed, I would be grateful.

Comment: Some very early discussion about magic links is [here on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments) and its Linked Posts.  It sounds like something not terribly difficult for Powers That Be to implement.

Comment: You can use an [app to customize](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/320281/403622) however you want, it seems.