# Adding the link of the MathJax tutorial in the Tour and/or the sidebar (bulletin) displayed when one is going to ask a question

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, asking-questions, new-users, tour

Can we include a prominent link to MathJax in the Tour, a suggested [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/33178/693774), and on the sidebar (bulletin) that displays on the right side when one is going to ask a question, as suggested in the comments by Martin Sleziak?

See also [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28919/adding-a-shortcut-link-for-the-mathjax-tutorial) and [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17134/should-mathjax-be-pointed-out-to-new-users) for related discussions, where all points out that a showy link would be more than helpful for new users.
Or perhaps, instead of the MathJax tutorial link, a   [How can I format Mathematics here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) link?

When one is going to ask a question, there are various links: the [Provide details](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960), the choose a good title, etc. I think the MathJax link explicitly is missing.

**Edit**

There's also this observation, when one is going to ask a question, this displays on the right sidebar.

[image]

Where there are 3 repeated links on both bulletins, the last 3 in the first bulletin and the 3 in the second bulletin.

**Edit 2** I've also thought about this previously, and made a comment about it [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33132/693774). Thanks to Martin Sleziak's notitification, reminded me about that.

Comment: When you say "in the sidebar", do you mean the part entitled "helpful links", which is shown when asking a question. (As displayed in [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pe0WL.png).) I actually added the ([meta-tag:asking-question]) tag, but then removed it, since the post does not really say which sidebar you mean. (If you mean this one, feel free to use the screenshot in your post.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak You're right. I was not clear enough.

Comment: Regarding the MathJax link, I suppose the ones mentioned here https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33179/